# Splitting files in Mercurial and retaining history on both sides

Tags: mercurial, plsql

I need to split a number of files and I'm looking for options to retain the full file history in the split-off files.

**Background...**

I've inherited a project containing lots of Oracle PL/SQL packages with the package spec and the package body all stored in a single ".sql" file. I'd prefer to have the package specification and package body in separate files.

i.e.

Starting with: `myfile.sql`

I'd like to split this file so that the first bit (package specification) goes in:

```
myfile.pks
```

and the last bit (package body) goes in:

```
myfile.pkb
```

I've no issues doing the separation itself, but I was wondering if anyone had any ideas how I could retain show the file history of `myfile.sql` both in `myfile.pks` and `myfile.pkb`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Splitting files can be modelled by `hg rename` and `hg copy` to retain the history:

```
hg copy  myfile.sql myfile.pks
hg rename myfile.sql  myfile.pkb
```

The edit the *.pks and *.pkb file to remove the half that doesn't belong there.

After the edit commit it all.

To see the copies and renames you have to use git format of diffs:

```
hg diff -g
```

Since this is very useful its often set as default in the `.hgrc`file by adding:

```
[diff]
    git=1
```

Answer (score 0):

IDEs make it even simpler. E.g. in IntelliJ select the file and do `Refactor` > `Copy`.